# webview document.getElementsByName() not implemented

Tags: c#, .net, webview, win-universal-app

I'm currently working in c# on universal app for w10, and I'm working with webview. 
I'm trying to run script over webview.Invoke()

```
string functionString = "document.getElementsByName('name').Value = 'jmeno';";
webView1.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

But I'm getting exception: **The method or operation is not implemented.**

Any ideas, or experiences about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your javascript is invalid, though I'm unsure if that'd throw the exception you're seeing.

Specify the index (i.e. `[0]`) of the element to set the "value" of:

```
string functionString = "document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value = 'jmeno';";
```

Comment: Generaly, this works thank You, only change - it is case sensitive and value with upper V throws ex.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx):

> InvokeScript may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows
>   8.1. Instead, use InvokeScriptAsync.

So on Windows 10 you should use [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx).